# Can a loss on the sale of my house offset capital gains tax from stock options?

Tags: united-states, taxes, options, capital-gain, primary-residence

I've lost a bunch of value on my primary residence.  I've got a bunch of vested stock options that, when exercised/sold, will be a substantial capital gains.

If I sold my house the same year I exercised/sold the options, would I save taxes by offsetting the gains with the losses?

(I'm in the US, California if it matters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a loss on the sale of a primary residence is not tax deductible (just as the gains are not taxable, up to a limit)

See here - [IRS Pub 523](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p523.pdf)

Specifically, on page 5:

> **Loss on sale.** If the amount realized is less than the adjusted basis,
>   the difference is a loss. A loss on the sale of your main home cannot
>   be deducted.

Comment: Yea, its only fair. You don't pay taxes on the gains!